# Customize the "other" box of a Google form

Tags: google-forms

I have a Google form and I want the "Other box" of a multiple-choice question to say something other than “Other”. For example:

```
Other programs:[                     ]
```

How to do it, if this is possible at all?

Comment: Really frustrating that it doesn't allow to modify the "other" option.

Answer (score 3):

Google forms do not appear to offer such customizability.

---

But it's possible to directly modify the HTML file provided by the form, and use the modified file instead of the form. Such restyling process is described [in this tutorial](http://morning.am/tutorials/how-to-style-google-forms/), and the [Sneaky Sheep tool](http://sneakysheep.com/google-docs-form-tool-version-2/) might make it easier. Here is a brief description.

1. Create the form
2. Go to Live Form
3. Right click the form, pick "View Source", copy-paste the entire source into a  text editor.
4. Replace the relative link near the top

```
<link href='/static/forms/client/css/....
```

with absolute link

```
<link href='https://docs.google.com/static/forms/client/css/....
```

so that it works from any location.

5. Replace "Other:" with "Other programs" (searching will help locating this string).
6. Put the HTML form somewhere where your users can access it. If you created it from a spreadsheet, it will still submit data to that spreadsheet.

Limitations of the above approach:

1. Works only for single-page forms.
2. If multiple responses are allowed, the standard page shown on submission will have a link to original form, not to your customized version. This can be worked around: search the source for "form action" and change the URL  to your custom confirmation page.

Comment: This is not working with the current version of Google Forms.