# Conditional required questions

Tags: google-forms

I am building a google form with several multiple-choice questions, I want to add a comment field below every question and make this comment required if the answer of the multiple-choice question is 3, 4, or 5. If the answer is 1 or 2, I want to allow comments, but this should not be required.

I am wondering if anyone knows how to create this?

Comment: Welcome. Please share a test form link so we can clearly understand your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Google Forms built-in features. One alternative is to use the HTML Service from Google Apps Script to build your form by using HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

NOTE: The old version of Google Forms isn't available anymore.

Related

- [Customize the "other" box of a Google form](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86688/88163)
- [How can I make a minimal, unstyled HTML form which works with Google Forms?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90693/88163)
- [Two yes-no questions, if both anwers are yes go to section 2 and 3, will skip section 2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103690/88163)